# Dictionary in android as app with eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to make an application in android like dictionary with eclipse . now the main question is that

1. we can not make an app which redirects you to another app in the same OS , what I mean is that Dictionary app is like this , we have a word we just click on it and it redirects us to another app like word-web to search the word .
2. What I think I want to do is that , our app is like this we have to print something in that app and its meaning comes out .

3 also we can do like this click on the word and it redirects you to a webpage

I am new to android app and these are my ideas I wanna know which is the one is right way to do . Also I was unable to find anything on net about dictionary like I want . if anyone can tell me whats the right way to introduce dictionary app and appropriate tutorial for that , it will be a pleasure to me .

Thank you

Comment: For number one, look up intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first option you are giving is not [possible because other apps don't allow you to do that but you can start with the 2nd one